# Alternating column values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am working on a project where my dataset looks like bellow:

| Origin | Destination | Num_Trips |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hamburg | Frankfurt | 2 |
| Hamburg | Cologne | 1 |
| Cologne | Hamburg | 3 |
| Frankfurt | Hamburg | 5 |

I am interested only on one way either "Hamburg - Frankfurt" or "Frankfurt - Hamburg" and add them as number of trips made between this two locations. How can i do this in pandas so that i have one of them in my dataset with the total number of trips made between the two points either side?

Final Table:

| Origin | Destination | Num_Trips |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hamburg | Frankfurt | 7 |
| Hamburg | Cologne | 4 |

Thanks :)

Comment: The distances are different for HAM-FRA and FRA-HAM. Do you have a preference which distance to use? Just the first one that shows up?

Comment: I have modified my original question, I think it is a little clearer now. Thank you for your answers sofar and I would appreciate any further suggestions you may offer :)

Comment: I didn't realize you modified the question completely a little while ago. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple solution to your problem -

```
data = {
    "Origin": ["Hamburg", "Hamburg", "Cologne", "Frankfurt"],
    "Destination": ["Frankfurt", "Cologne", "Hamburg", "Hamburg"],
    "Num_Trips": [2, 1, 3, 5]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["Key"] = df[["Origin", "Destination"]].apply(lambda x: "|".join(set(x)), axis=1)
# Origin    Destination Num_Trips   Key
# Hamburg   Frankfurt   2           Frankfurt|Hamburg
# Hamburg   Cologne     1           Cologne|Hamburg
# Cologne   Hamburg     3           Cologne|Hamburg
# Frankfurt Hamburg     5           Frankfurt|Hamburg

df.groupby("Key").agg({"Origin": "first", 
                       "Destination": "first", 
                       "Num_Trips": sum}).reset_index(drop=True)

#   Origin  Destination Num_Trips
# 0 Hamburg Cologne     4
# 1 Hamburg Frankfurt   7
```

Comment: I would avoid using methods like using  `"-".join`. Take this example: Origin = 'A', Destination = 'B-C' and another row having Origin = 'A-B', Destination = 'C'. I know its rare situation that these can occur but can eventually be cause of a break.

Comment: @SomeDude interesting and rare scenario, but I agree to your point. In that case, some rarely used characters in should do the job. I will edit the solution to use pipe `|` character as separator.

Answer (score 1):

You can do ( assuming you want to keep the first duplicate entry ):

```
out = (
df.groupby(df[['Origin', 'Destination']].apply(
        lambda x: str(sorted((x['Origin'], x['Destination']))), axis=1)).agg(
    {'Origin':'first',
     'Destination':'first',
     'Num_Trips':'sum'
    }).
    reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

print(out):

```
    Origin Destination  Num_Trips
0  Hamburg     Cologne          4
1  Hamburg   Frankfurt          7
```

Answer (score -1):

IIUC, you can try

```py
cols = ['Origin', 'Destination']
vals = ['Hamburg', 'Frankfurt']

out = df[(df[cols] == vals).all(axis=1) | (df[cols] == vals[::-1]).all(axis=1)]
```

```
print(out)

      Origin Destination  distance
0    Hamburg   Frankfurt    393.34
3  Frankfurt     Hamburg    400.44
```

Answer (score -1):

#### Arpit Tiwari (Data Scientist)

```
import pandas as pd
dict1 = {'Origin':['Hamburg', 'Hamburg', 'Cologne', 'Frankfurt'],
        'Destination':['Frankfurt', 'Cologne', 'Hamburg', "Hamburg"],
        'distance':[393.34, 357.15, 358.24, 400.44]
       }
X = pd.DataFrame(dict1)

## Please refer to this part
X['Key'] = (X['Origin']+X['Destination']).apply(lambda x:"".join(sorted(x)))
X=X.drop_duplicates(subset=['Key'],keep='first').drop('Key',axis=1)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).